# Background color change on hover of a row not working (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery, css

I am facing background color change problem while using jquery.

When the page loads for the first time and the user hovers over a table row, the table row's background changes.

Once the user clicks on table row cell to generate a jquery popup, the background color changes of the row that the popup belongs to.

One the user closes the the popup window (using jquery) by clicking anywhere on the document, the highlight on hover feature for the rows mentioned on the first line, get disabled, and I need it to remain in effect as long as none of the popup windows are open.

This is what I tried to add to my jquery, which works until one of the popups are shown once. In otherwords, the code below is triggered once only, rather than remaining in effect like i need to:

```
if($(".webpopup,.phonepopup").is(":hidden")){
    $("tr").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fresh');
    });
}
```

js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vUWsb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `!important`:

```
.fresh{background-color:#ddd !important;}

$("tr").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('fresh');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fresh')    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vUWsb/6/

---

Something like this?

```
 $("tr").hover(function(e){
        if ($(".webpopup, .phonepopup").is(":visible")) {
           return false;
        }
       $(this).addClass('fresh');     
    }, function() {
       $(this).removeClass('fresh');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vUWsb/10/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This is the closest to what I need so far. Again, I would like to disable the 'on hover' event and change the background color permanently while popups are open AND I would like to enable this 'on hover' event while popups are hidden. Your jsfiddle is kind of a demonstration of a combination of the two:)

Comment: I appreciate the effort, haha you're very close, but not exactly. I would like to apply the permanent background change if and only if the popup is open. Otherwise, (if the popups are hidden), I would like to trigger than on hover event and disable the 'permanent' background change.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to me like the hover is not working after you click on a cell. Rather, it looks like you are setting the background to be the default white when clicking a table cell:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $("#favorites-table tr").css({
        "background-color": "#fff" // <--- this part
    });
    $(".webpopup, .phonepopup").hide();
});
```

Since inline styling takes precedence over styling with classes, you would never see the hover effect because it is being hidden by the background color you are setting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I tried to delete that line, and rather than changing the background color on hover, it changes it permanently.

Comment: @MHZ, try removing all the instances where you are setting inline styles. Since you do not remove these inline colors, they are basically permanent. Have a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vUWsb/5/). It seems to work for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help, however, this does not work for the same reason that @stevether doesn't work. Please check my response to his example. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to base it off your 'fresh' class instead.

Things like

```
    $("#favorites-table tr").css({
        "background-color": "#fff"
    });
```

Add an inline style, which trumps the class css.

Use `addClass` and `removeClass` instead

http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/vUWsb/2/

Comment: Not what I am looking for. The way it is set up in my jsfiddle is correct, I would like the background color to change for that row, permantly while a popup is visible. While a popup is not visibile, I would like to trigger an 'on hover' event that changes the background color of the row on hover (which is what I am having trouble with). Your jsfiddle works on hover only.

Answer (score 0):

Other contributions rightly pointed out that you need to use classes instead of inline colors, but as MHZ keeps saying, this is not all of the desired functionality. The problem with the hover is that the way it's trying to test for visibility is incorrect. Consider the original test for visibility:

```
if($(".webpopup,.phonepopup").is(":hidden")){
    $("tr").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fresh');
    });
}
```

The if function will always result in true. Then, since it's always true, it will create the hover event. This happens once, on document load. Then you're stuck with this event listener.

Instead, MHZ, I think you want something like the following:

```
theyAreVisible = function() {
    var shown = $('.webpopup,.phonepopup').map(function() {
        return $(this).is(':visible') ? true : null;
    });
    return shown.length > 0 ? true : false;
};

$("tr").hover(function() {
    if (!theyAreVisible()) $(this).addClass('fresh');
}, function() {
    if (!theyAreVisible()) $(this).removeClass('fresh');

});
```

This way, you have one hover event handler that checks to see whether any of the pop ups are open. The map function will loop through each and find if any individual is open and return true if it finds any. BUT we can't just return this result because if([]) will resolve as true. Consider:

```
if ([]) { console.log('yup!'); }
```

Take-away:

1. Always do your checks within your event handlers (toggle, in this case)
2. Make sure that the things you think are resolving as true are actually resolving as true.

Comment: Now I see that @undefined's answer is much more elegant. I have a way of overdoing things.